# python crontab makec freezed

Tags: python, cron

I'm writing a test script using python
I have a 'makec 'command in my script.
I set up crontab to run my script every hour,
here's the crontab command i use( all in one line)

```
20 * * * * cd /project/work/account/auto_test/ ;   
/project/tools/bin/python3   
/project/work/lichuan/auto_test/revision.py  >> 
/project    /work/account/auto_test/crontab.txt 2>&1
```

Here's the email i received

```
/bin/sh: line 1: 19047 Terminated              
/project/tools/bin/python3 /project/work/account/auto_test/revision.py >>
/project/work/account/auto_test/crontab.txt 2>&1
```

Seems like the process froze at the 'makec' command, no more output after this log

```
/sirius/tools/python3/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py:389: RuntimeWarning: 
The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. 
Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
```

"program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)

I have this runtime warning before in my script but it works well so I'm not sure where the problem is. 
Right now it seems that problem becomes stuck with the makec command, but I do have one cp command before makec so I think there's nothing wrong with os lib

Thanks

Comment: `MakeC` is not the same as `CMake`, which you use as a tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the note

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I figure it out. We may learn from the other webs that we need absolute path for configure files. Same applies to command. After I give abs path to my makec command e.g:

```
/tools/bin/makec ----options
```

Everything works.